# IME options for edit text Enter and Done together

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

Is there a way to show Enter and Done option together in soft keyboard for the editText. Thanks in advance.
I can use done and enter options seperatly. bout could not find any way to use this together. In my application, I need to use these together.

Comment: This is the one you want
   android:imeOptions="actionSend"

Comment: I think it is not possible...

Comment: actionSend gives the send button instead of enter or done.